# make command gives Incompatible i386 architecture(i386x86-64)

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

Im having trouble using my make file for a program i am writing in a linux environment. The program is a fern fractal that uses bitmapImage.h and bitmapImage.so given to me by my professor. Whenever i attempt to run the make file i get a long string of errors, the main one being :

```
    make
g++    -c -o fern.o fern.cpp
g++    -c -o fernType.o fernType.cpp
g++ -m32 -o fern fern.o fernType.o bitmapImage.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [spiro] Error 1
```

*my guess is that the bitmapImage.so is designed for a 32 bit system, but my virtual machine ubuntu runs 64-bit. How do i go about fixing this so i can compile my program? Thanks!*

EDIT: updated my old post to show the current error i am getting

MakeFile:

```
# Make file for spirograph program

## note, uses bitmapImage shared object file (library).

OBJS = fern.o fernType.o
CC  = g++ -m32
DEPS1 = fernType.h
DEPS2 = bitmapImage.h

all: spiro

spiro: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -m32 -o fern $(OBJS) bitmapImage.so

spiro.o:    fern.cpp $(DEPS1)
    $(CC) -m32 -c fern.cpp

spiroType.o:    fernType.cpp $(DEPS1) $(DEPS2)
    $(CC) -m32 -c fernType.cpp

# -----
# clean by removing object files.

clean:
    rm  $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `-m32` option to your compilation lines, that forces everything to be compiled for a 32-bit address space.  (It will still run on a 64-bit system.)

Comment: where exactly would i add that? So if i run:   $ make -m32 it should work?

Comment: No, like `$(CC) -m32 -o ...` for all of your compile lines.  Or change your `CC` line to read `CC = g++ -m32`.

Comment: sorry for my lack of intelligence toward this subject, currently i just type 'make' in my terminal directory and it makes the executable. I dont quite understand what you mean my "for all of your compile lines". Thanks again for your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: Edit your `Makefile` with the change I suggested.  Then `make` as usual.  (You might need to `make clean` also.)

Comment: Alright, so i added that into my makefile and it removed that error, but im getting a new string of errors, ill update my post

Comment: You need to add the `-m32` to *all 3* compile lines.

Comment: Added the -m32 to each line, tried with and without the CC = g++ -m32 but nothing has changed from the error im getting. From what it seems my g++ libraries are only 64-bit? meaning i cant compile this?

Comment: It is possible you don't have 32-bit gcc properly installed, but I suspect not.  Try running the three commands directly on the command line instead of using the makefile.  `g++ -m32 -c -o fern.o fern.cpp`, `g++ -m32 -c -o fernType.o fernType.cpp`, and then `g++ -m32 -o fern fern.o fernType.o bitmapImage.so`.  Append the commands you ran and the results you got to your question.

Comment: appreciate the help! if this doesn't work ill try and get my teacher to write a 64-bit version for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly the problem -- you can't link a 32-bit object file with a 64-bit object file.  You need to either:

- Compile on a 32-bit machine (real or virtual),
- Ask your professor for a 64-bit library, or
- Ask for the source code to the library so you can compile it all yourself

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `file` to see if, indeed, the shared lib is 32-bit.
2. If it is, you'll have to acquire a 64-bit copy of it somehow.